# how to display map like this using openlayers

Tags: openlayers

I want to display my map like this, but i can't find a similar example. Can someone help me. Thank you

[image: map]

Answer (score 3):

Looking at OL3's [Flight Animation Example](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.12.1/examples/flight-animation.html), it appears to be possible using the [arc.js](https://github.com/springmeyer/arc.js) plugin: “A great circle arc between two airports is calculated using arc.js and then the flight paths are animated with postcompose. The flight data is provided by [OpenFlights](http://openflights.org/data.html) (a simplified data set from the Mapbox.js documentation is used).”
[image: Screenshot of OpenLayers3's Flight Animation Example]